# PHP-AJAX; POST METHOD problem

Tags: php, post

I am using ajax, php with my application.
In sending the data from ajax to php, when i use the $_GET, I can have the data.
but when i try to use $_POST since i read it is more secure, it cannot access the data.
When i echo the value, it's blank.

I tried changing the register_globals = off to on in the
php.ini, but still not working.

did i miss out on something?

### this is my js file:

```
var params=arguments[0].options[arguments[0].selectedIndex].value;
 var url = "http://localhost/myprocess.php";
 ajaxRequest.open("POST",url, true);

 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length",params.length);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if ((ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) && (ajaxRequest.status == 200)) 
    {
    //Get data from server's response
    alert("response text is:");
    alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);   -->does not show anything; blank
   }
  }
 ajaxRequest.send(params);
}
```

---

### php file

```
<?php
$selectedID = $_POST['params'];
echo "hello there ". $selectedID;
?>
```

---

thanks a lot,
tinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you specifying a key for the data that's being POSTed, which is what your PHP script is looking for.

Try changing `ajaxRequest.send(params);` to `ajaxRequest.send("params=" + params);`

Comment: i would rather try ajaxRequest.send("params=" + params);

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you need to specify a key. The post method on this link might help:

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: hey guys!! thank you so much! yeah it needed the key.. it is working now!!! thank you! :D